# PHP - Fetching UTF-8 data from sqlsrv database

Tags: php, utf-8, sqlsrv

I'm Trying to fetch some data from sql server database and print in json , but some of the data in database is in UTF-8 (Arabic) . I searched the web and tried many solutions , but none of them worked for me , any help would be appreciated . Here is my code :

```
<?php

$serverName = "127.0.0.1"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"filmnak_com_", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8", "UID"=>"filmnak", "PWD"=>"G5j^wk44");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

$sql = "SELECT CAST(ID AS INT) AS ID, CAST(Film AS TEXT) AS Film ,CAST(Name AS TEXT) Name FROM dbo.Movies";

$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $result === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["Info"] = array();
  while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $Info = array();
        $Info["ID"] = $row["ID"] ;
        $Info["Film"] = $row["Film"];

      $Info["Name"] = utf8_decode($row["Name"]);

    echo $row["Name"];
        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["Info"], $Info);
    }


echo json_encode($response , JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

sqlsrv_free_stmt($result);


?>
```

the result in browser :

```
???? ????1+1?????{"Info":[{"ID":8,"Film":"8O9","Name":"???? ????"},{"ID":9,"Film":"9O3","Name":"1+1"},{"ID":10,"Film":"10O5","Name":"?????"}]}
```

Comment: are you set `collation ` ?? like this `Arabic_CI_AI`

Comment: + use the type `nvarchar` (or other similar like `ntext`, `nchar`

Comment: utf8_decode never does what you think it does. If your data is UTF 8 in the database and your connection charset is UTF 8 then PHP will receive it as UTF 8. PHP can handle UTF-8 just fine, no need for any special operations on them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @apokryfos , the data in database is UTF-8 , I set the characterset to UTF-8 , but when i use echo to print them , it will show question marks (?????) , ( echo $row["Name"]; gives question marks , utf8_decode($row["Name"]); gives question marks )

Comment: @ArashMohammadi you must say, are you tried of my previous comments?

Comment: @Karthi , yes I changed the collation to Arabic_CI_AI and it worked fine , I  posted a comment here before about this but I dont know why the comment is not showing now , sry for that and TY for the solution

Comment: okay okay no problem @ArashMohammadi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the database collation to `utf8_general_ci`

Answer (score 17):

USE THIS CODE

```
    $serverName="(local)";
    $connetionInfo = array("DataBase"=>"your db","UID"=>"username","PWD"=>"pass",
                           "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");<---------------this
    $this->dblink=sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connetionInfo);
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to specify the character set when connecting to the sqlsrv server. You can do this by adding the `CharacterSet` parameter like this:

```
$serverName = "Your server name";
$connectionInfo = [ "Database"=>"your db",  "CharacterSet" =>"UTF-8"];
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```